# Marking places in android app not on the 'Google Places' database

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, google-places-api

I want to add markers on map for my android app. I do know how to do it (overlay items). **My question is:** Since I am manually putting markers on points(on the map) whose lat/long's I already know, I want to know if there is any way to get the exact latitude and longitude of a place on google map? Right now I am asking my people to go to the particular places and use this ( http://bit.ly/K4fOcy ) app to determine the lat/long of that place and send it to me via e-mail. I use these lat/long values to put markers on my map in the app. But the latitudes and longitudes i get are not accurate. they have around 300-2500m error (on real scale).
   Or shall I use the Google Places API? How does it work? What about the places which are not in the Google Places database? How do I exactly mark them on the map? I would be very grateful if someone points me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with establishments that aren't represented in the Google Places API and want to be able to pull coordinates directly from http://maps.google.com/, you simply:

1. Find the location of interest on the map, using an address or just knowledge of the area
2. Right-click on the map and select **What's here?** from the context pop-up menu

The Lat-Lng coordinates will be automatically populated in the search input box and usually, the address will also be displayed in the dynamic side-panel (and very often a Street-View photo).

If you are looking for a way to query for the coordinates, you can use the Geocoder[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) service to turn addresses into coordinates.

Comment: thanks! i will probably use the geocoder service. our database is huge. manually right-clicking on the map and finding the lat/longs' of each establishment will be cumbersome.We do have the addresses of each establishment (restaurants, in our case) in our database which we can pull and use the geocoder to get the points and mark them. lets see how stuff works out  :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the geocoding API for google maps? It allows you to pass in an address, and returns a Latitude/Longitude pair in response, there is an accuracy value returned with each response to let you know how close the geocoder was able to resolve the location. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: yes i did. in fact i use that. i want to know how do i mark an establishment(in my case, restaurants) on the map in my android app if that place is not available in the google maps or google places?